# How can I find big content to delete on my PS3?

Tags: ps3

I keep running out of space on my 250GB PS3, thanks in large part of my PS+ subscription.  Every time I go to download a new big game, I have to trawl through the stuff I'm not using to find what's taking up so much space.

I haven't seen a way to "sort by size" or anything, and sometimes the big stuff is hiding in a subfolder -- I know about the Game Data Utility, but there are also some that put big files in the regular Save Data too.  Checking every single entry is incredibly time-consuming.

Is there a simple way to pull up big files I haven't used in a long time?

Answer (score -1):

if you have multi language game go to a file menager and delete all language that you dont need ,russian italian etc. that give some about 5 GB on every game.